# showUserLocation changes when setting MapView delegate to self

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, core-location

I'm new to the CoreLocation and MapKit and I have this weird problem. Basically, I have a MKMapView displayed in a UIView. When I set up my MKMapView like this :

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
//self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

I get this (1):

[image]

But when I uncomment the second line, I get this (2) which I find weird.

[image]

How could I do to set the delegate of the MKMapView to self, but still get the (1)

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you switch the order of the two lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you overwriting the annotations (`viewForAnnotation` method) in your Controller? It looks to me that when you set the delegate to self, the annotation is beeing overwritten.

If you do change the annotation in your Class then add the following lines. This will prevent changing the annotation of the "Current location" point.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    // Check if its the annotation for displaying the current position
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    // Your annotation code

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But what do you mean by 'overwriting the annotations in my controller'.

Comment: I once had a similar problem. Where I was changing the annotation icons. I was overwriting the annotation method as shown in the code sample above. But I was overwriting all the annotations (inclucind the current location icon). In your Controller class where the self is delegating to, did you had there before a method implemented like above: - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation?